# Excel file generated using phpexcel is not opening after downloading from server

Tags: php, phpexcel

I generated and downloaded one excel file using `PHP Excel` and it's working fine in `localhost`.

But when I uploaded it to the server, it is downloading, but when opening the file it displays the error message:

```
Excel cannot open the file [filename] because the file format or file extension is not valid.
```

I don't know whether it`s a problem with headers. 
The headers that I am using are the following:

```
header('Content-Type: application/vnd.openxmlformats-officecdocument.spreadsheetml.sheet');
header('Content-Disposition:attachment;filename="01simple.xlsx"');
header('Cache-Control:max-age=0');
```

I found similar question, but none of them are answered precisely.

Comment: can you check with firebug or something similar that the headers are set correctly on you prod server?

Comment: Open the downloaded file in a text editor, and look for any leading/trailing whitespace or BOM header, or for any visible plaintext PHP error messages anywhere in the file.... this should be the first step to diagnose any occurrence of this error message provided in any answer to similar questions

Comment: @MarkBaker: I saw you answer before for some similar kind of questions in this forum. But I didn't undestand one thing that, if there are some leading/trailing whitespace or BOM header or anything like that , how come it is downloading and viewable in the local server???

Comment: Because anything that is output in any way will be output.... that includes characters between `?>` and `<?php` tags in your code, echo or print statements, error messages that are displayed by PHP, etc.... all go to `php://output`..... if you have errors on your server because of different configuration compared with your localhost (e.g. lower memory limits causing problems, or errors because php_zip is missing or whatever) those can trigger outputs that don't happen on localhost

Comment: @MarkBaker: I checked the downloaded file with a text editor. Like I told you, the file downloaded in the localhost doesn't had any problem . But when I open the file which is downloaded from the server, it is showing the error and blank excel sheet. 
In the text editor, the server file shows some exception message but not in the localhost file.
THe message is like "<br />
<b>Warning</b>:  mysql_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in ...etc...".
Or if there is any problem with the php_zip file in server, how can I sort that problem??????

Comment: You sort it by fixing the `mysql_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in` error..... if that code works on your localhost, it probably means a problem with your database connection

Comment: Yeah, I am using left join and its a very large table. When I run the query in server it displays an error "#1104 - The SELECT would examine more than MAX_JOIN_SIZE rows; check your WHERE and use SET SQL_BIG_SELECTS=1 or SET MAX_JOIN_SIZE=# if the SELECT is okay".
Do you have any idea what is this error?

Comment: Looks like you need to configure your database to handle a query involving so much data, or modify your query to be less resource demanding.... but without knowing anything about your database, query and volumes of data involved I cant really provide any meaningful answer - you might be better posting details of that error as a new question, tagged MySQL (if that's the database you're using) so that people who have a good understanding of that database can see it

Comment: Thank you Baker. Actually my problem got solved when I added mysql_query("SET SQL_BIG_SELECTS=1"); at the beginning of all my queries. I found so many problems similar to mine and I came to know that it is something which refer to the left join and bigger tables...
Anyway thanks for your support......